# Conditional Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to use conditional expressions in a Spring config?

E.g. I'd like to define two different connectors like this:

Connector 1:

```
<spring:bean id="MyConnector" class="org.test.provider.DBConnector">
    <spring:property name="host" value="${my.config.host}"/>
    <spring:property name="user" value="${my.config.user}"/>
    <spring:property name="password" value="${my.config.password}"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Connector 2:

```
<spring:bean id="MyConnector" class="org.test.provider.FileSystemConnector">
    <spring:property name="path" value="${my.config.path}"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Then, later, use one of those like this:

```
<spring:bean id="LookupCommand" class="org.test.lookup.LookupCommand"
    scope="prototype">
    <spring:property name="connector" ref="MyConnector"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Depending on, lets say, `${my.config.connectorType}` from my .cfg file, I'd like to chose/activate one of those two:

```
if ${my.config.connectorType} == DB then

    <spring:bean id="MyConnector" class="org.test.provider.DBConnector">
        <spring:property name="host" value="${my.config.host}"/>
        <spring:property name="user" value="${my.config.user}"/>
        <spring:property name="password" value="${my.config.password}"/>
    </spring:bean>

else

    <spring:bean id="MyConnector" class="org.test.provider.FileSystemConnector">
        <spring:property name="path" value="${my.config.path}"/>
    </spring:bean>
end
...
<spring:bean id="LookupCommand" class="org.test.lookup.LookupCommand"
    scope="prototype">
    <spring:property name="connector" ref="MyConnector"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Comment: jeejava.com/conditional-statement-in-spring-config/

Answer (score 7):

A simple alternative solution. Give different names for each connector as below

```
<spring:bean id="dbConnector" class="org.test.provider.DBConnector">
    <spring:property name="host" value="${my.config.host}"/>
    <spring:property name="user" value="${my.config.user}"/>
    <spring:property name="password" value="${my.config.password}"/>
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="fileConnector" class="org.test.provider.FileSystemConnector">
    <spring:property name="path" value="${my.config.path}"/>
</spring:bean>
```

In your properties file, specify the name of the connector you wish to connect like my.config.connectorType=`dbConnector`

In LookupCommand bean, refer this property as below

```
<spring:bean id="LookupCommand" class="org.test.lookup.LookupCommand"
    scope="prototype">
    <spring:property name="connector" ref="${my.config.connectorType}"/>
</spring:bean>
```

Note: I initially thought of suggesting [bean definition profile](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released#enter-bean-definition-profiles) but you have to pass system properties `-Dspring.profiles.active` in your JVM. I'm trying to avoid that and in the above method you don't have the hassle to set any JVM system properties.

Comment: I was thinking about a profile too, but I don't want to do that (my code runs in a bundle in an OSGi container).

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative approach: [Bean definition profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released#enter-bean-definition-profiles). Have these nested `<beans>` elements in your XML file:

```
<beans profile="db1">
    <bean id="MyConnector" ...>
        ...
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="db2">
    <bean id="MyConnector" ...>
        ...
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and add `spring.profiles.active` to your environment variables like this:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="db1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create 2 different property files. Let's say they have name `DB.properties` and `filesystem.properties`. After that by using `property-placeholder` you can refer to your property files by this:

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/config/${my.config.connectorType}.properties"/>
```

If you start your application with '-Dmy.config.connectorType=DB' JVM parameter, then `DB.properties` file will be loaded.

```
<spring:bean id="MyDbConnector" class="org.test.provider.DBConnector" lazy-init="true">
    <spring:property name="host" value="${my.config.host}"/>
    <spring:property name="user" value="${my.config.user}"/>
    <spring:property name="password" value="${my.config.password}"/>
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="MyFileSystemConnector" class="org.test.provider.FileSystemConnector" lazy-init="true">
    <spring:property name="path" value="${my.config.path}"/>
</spring:bean>

<alias name="${my.connector}" alias="MyConnector"/>

<spring:bean id="LookupCommand" class="org.test.lookup.LookupCommand"
scope="prototype">
    <spring:property name="connector" ref="MyConnector"/>
</spring:bean>
```

`DB.properties`:
    my.connector=MyDbConnector
`filesystem.properties`:
    my.connector=MyFileSystemConnector

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for a solution, I feel [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235311/access-application-properties-within-spel-in-spring-xml-configuration/46240360#46240360) is an answer that speaks closest to the desired behaviour - using a ternary operator in the bean definition.