# Access application properties within SpEL in Spring xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-el

I'm trying to configure a spring bean based on an application property, my end goal is described in the following pseudo code:

```
if ${my.config}
    <bean id="myBean" class="path.to.MyBeanImplOne" />
else
    <bean id="myBean" class="path.to.MyBeanImplTwo" />
end
```

where `my.config` is a boolean property.
According to [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language) SpEL guide, `#{${my.config} ? 'path.to.MyBeanImplOne' : 'path.to.MyBeanImplTwo'}` is a valid expression, so I tried the following configuration:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="#{${my.config} ? 'path.to.MyBeanImplOne' : 'path.to.MyBeanImplTwo'}" />
```

but got the following exception:

```
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

I can't find documentation for accessing properties in SpEL expressions for xml configuration. Is this supported only in Java configuration?

I've seen a number of proposed solutions to my problem (some of which are in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872644/conditional-spring-configuration)). I'd like to not use [systemProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based) since I feel this sort of configuration should not be specified a run arguments, and I feel the use of [profiles](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released#enter-bean-definition-profiles) is overkill for this particular use case.

Has someone been able to do what I've attempted successfully? Or can someone confirm whether or not the syntax I've tried to use is indeed not supported in xml configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class="#{'${my.config}'.equals('true') ? 'path.to.MyBeanImplOne' : 'path.to.MyBeanImplTwo'}"
```

**EDIT**

This works for me...

```
<bean id="foo" class="#{'${my.config}'.equals('true') ? 'java.lang.Integer' : 'java.lang.String'}">
    <constructor-arg value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I've tried that too, but I got an exception because it could not convert the String to Boolean, meaning it did not extract the property, but instead treated it as a String.

Comment: but i got the error
 `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [#{'true'.equals('true') ? 'java.lang.Integer' : 'java.lang.String'}] for bean with name 'foo' defined in class path resource [spring/command-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: #{'true'.equals('true') ? 'java.lang.Integer' : 'java.lang.String'}`

. 
spring-version 3.2.3.RELEASE . what could be wrong here ?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. Ask a new question and provide **much more information**, including your configuration. Spring 3.2.x is no longer supported so you should upgrade to a much more recent release.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SpEL in application.properties file unfortunately.

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation.)

> SpEL expressions from application property files are not processed at time of parsing these files and populating the environment. However, it is possible to write a SpEL expression in @Value. If the value of a property from an application property file is a SpEL expression, it will be evaluated when consumed through @Value.